# Does Go crypto/tls require a private key for client TLS certificate?

Tags: go, tls1.2, mtls

I'm implementing mutual TLS between 2 apps, both using Go.

One app runs on macOS and has a client TLS private key in the keychain that cannot be extracted.

I must use the Apple API (via CGO) to create a signature:

```objectivec
CFDataRef SecKeyCreateSignature(SecKeyRef key, SecKeyAlgorithm algorithm, CFDataRef dataToSign, CFErrorRef  _Nullable *error);
```

Does Go `crypto/tls` provide a callback for creating a mutual TLS signature without having to provide the client certificate private key?

I see the following callbacks in `tls.Config`, but they don't seem to be relevant to my situation:

- `VerifyPeerCertificate`
- `VerifyConnection`

Comment: Maybe a custom `crypto.Signer` that interfaces with Apple's API via CGO could Work. The callbacks are Just for customize the verification proccess.